# Hi, Do you know how to display an object over other objects on the app screen in Android Studio? (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, imageview, screen

For example, I have a list on the screen and I want a certain action to bounce an image in the center of the screen (like a dialog) but the image does not appear when the app is running , it seems to be hiding behind the list. Do you know if there is a command that will cause the image to appear in front of the screen (above all other objects on the screen)?

Comment: Without any code it's difficult to see what you're doing. I would recommend taking a look at [ask] for details on how to ask a great question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `View.bringToFront()`
or from the view's parent `ParentView.bringToFront(childView)`

Here is the function documantion:

> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other sibling views. This ordering change may affect layout, if the parent container uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g., LinearLayout). Prior to Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT this method should be followed by calls to requestLayout() and invalidate() on the view's parent to force the parent to redraw with the new child ordering.